# Why is my account not there?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-accounts

I had some ideas in JavaScript template engine, and had implemented a beta version of JavaScript lib, which I think, can serve as an alternative way to JavaScript engine.

I posted this in three different related questions. I don't think my posts are spam.

1. [Javascript template engine which would come with a precompilation script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331051/javascript-template-engine-which-would-come-with-a-precompilation-script/6343327)
   In this post, someone asked for some js template engine, that has a precompilation script and watcher feature. It is in my future implementation, so I responded to this post.
2. [Good Javascript template engine to work with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929111/good-javascript-template-engine-to-work-with-json/6353877)
   In this post, someone asked to recommend a js template engine, and I think my idea should be interesting to him, if not his ideal solution.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend/6354204
   In this post, someone asked 'What javascript templating engine do you recommend?'. I did the same thing.

I know my solution is sort of too detailed, but I simply don't think I have done anything bad to the community. It feels bad for contributing to the community.
I claim my profile back!

Can any admin explain the situation?

Comment: Are you serious? It's quite obvious you are spamming the site with your product.

Comment: Yea, you are right. anyway, I know how to correct this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see your previous account was deleted, but I'm not sure who did it.

I am sure that your answers were flagged as spam by members of the community, and that (probably) a mod saw you were a new account, had only answered three questions (one recent, but two from over a year ago, which is a hallmark of spammers), all of which referred people to your website, and all of which had essentially the same content (copy/pasted answers).  That usually will get your account deleted.  Only users with higher rep who have been around longer will be handled differently.

The community is very *very* sensitive to spam, even for products which are free or open source. You might have noticed in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) [(that noone reads)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95224/faq-huhn-what-is-it-good-for);

> "Be careful, because the community
>   frowns on overt self-promotion and
>   tends to vote it down and flag it as
>   spam. Post good, relevant answers, and
>   if they happen to be about your
>   product or website, so be it. However,
>   you must disclose your affiliation in
>   your answers. Also, if a huge
>   percentage of your posts include a
>   mention of your product or website,
>   you're probably here for the wrong
>   reasons."

If you do a search here on Meta for [self promotion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=self%20promotion), you may learn more about how the community perceives your actions, and how best to go about answering a question to suggest a product that you either own or support.

BTW, StackOverflow gives away free advertising to open source projects, [if you can come up with a good ad for it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011)

Comment: Just curious. If I post again, without copy and paste.. it would be ok. Right?

Comment: @LiangliangZheng: if you fully disclose your association in your profile, state your association in the answer, and make sure that your answer is 100% relevant to the question, you can try again.  Mods can't keep people from flagging you for spam.  So if you were to re-create your account and answer, you might be seen by the same people who flagged you the first time, which would kick up a nice s-storm.  I'd relax for a bit, read through the questions about self promotion here to get a better feel about the community, and try again later.

Answer (score 12):

Quite simply you have posted **exactly** the same answer three times the main aim of which appears to be to promote your own site.

This is considered to be spam.

Therefore your account has been deleted as a spammer account.

Comment: T.T
At least, I didn't mean to do this..
Granted, I posted three times... I thought that fits the question, plus typing something that long would kill me, so I typed once and pasted to the others.

Comment: @Liangliang - If it looks like a duck, walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's a duck. This is a simple paste of your promotional material and doesn't really address the question. It looks like spam, it reads like spam, therefore (as far as I can see) it is spam. I should point out that I had nothing to do with flagging any of your posts or deleting your account.

Answer (score 2):

You're posting the same answer promoting your product in a less than stellar way. Your answer is too long and goes into specifics about areas that the questioner has not asked or showed interest in. All that text is really just bloat and doesn't add anything.

If you want to promote a product that you developed *and which solves the OP's question*, you can do so. But you have to keep your answer to the point. Keep it concise and point him to the correct resources with a bit of text giving an intro. You're not supposed to be making a sales pitch.