# Wrong answer count for some questions: deleted answers calculated, but not visible

Tags: bug, status-norepro, deleted-answers

When I opened [Entity framework large data set, out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169859/entity-framework-large-data-set-out-of-memory-exception) ( on Windows 10 laptop with Chrome browser), the page  shows 
"3 Answers", but actually only 1 answer is visible. 
I am 10K+ user and I am logged in, so I should see deleted answers (one of them is my old answer)
I am able to see the same page on iPad's Safari with all 3 answers visible.

Similarly [ASP.Net raises error "System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified;" when switching to Vietnamese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710966/asp-net-raises-error-system-invalidoperationexception-collection-was-modified?answertab=active#tab-top) shows that it has "1 Answer", but no answers are visible. Again, on iPad I can see one deleted answer.
[image: !]

The problem is similar to [Wrong count of answers in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95240/wrong-count-of-answers-in-question), but explanation about sync daily job is not applicable for me, as all related answers were deleted a long time ago, and the issue with the second example I've noticed many days ago(and still able to reproduce).

Comment: Are you sure you're still logged in when you don't see the deleted answers? (For example, check the top bar, your username should appear there.) Maybe you can post a (zoomed out) screenshot?

Comment: @Glorfindel: Yes, I am logged in, I see my photo  and I just received notification about your comment.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Logout and login and maybe clear your browser's cookies.

Comment: @RobertLongson: quite possible,  logout will fix the issue(the deleted answers are visible in different browser), but I am reporting inconsistency: If I logged-in, I should see "1 answer" in header and 1 actual deleted answer. If I  am not logged-in, I should see 'no answers'  in header and no visible answers.

Comment: Could any of your extensions/userscripts be causing this?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim well yes but without more information all we can do is close it as not reproducible.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: Quite possible. The issue seems specific to Chrome only, persists after logout, open in new instance of Chrome and  login. I am running 2 Tampermonkey scripts "SE Comment Link Helper" and "stackoverflow-comment-reply", but neither of them (AFAIK)hide deleted answers

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: I've installed just now "Stack Exchange Deleted Answer Manager"  Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-exchange-deleted-an/hmcfjaackkkkohogfoofjbfohjgpmibn) and it make header more meaningful, e.g "1 Relevant Answer, 2 Deleted Answers". However the extension has an option "show deleted answers", but it doesn't make them visible.

Comment: When you can't see any answers (without the extension), does entering `$('.answer')` in the browser console show anything? (so is the answer actually present in the DOM but hidden with CSS?)

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this. Sounds like one of the extensions you're running is doing something wonky there.