# Are Thank You's and Me Too's also frowned upon in the comments to a question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Official reference for “don't leave ‘thank you’ comments”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101124/official-reference-for-dont-leave-thank-you-comments)

I can imagine me too's being frowned upon, since that's what the upvote button is for. But Thank you's from the OP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Me too" comments are always frowned upon.

"Thank you" comments from the asker aren't encouraged, [but they're tolerated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101124/official-reference-for-dont-leave-thank-you-comments/101126#101126). It's best to delete the comment a few hours/days later, so that the answerer gets your thanks but the clutter is removed from the page.