# The "thank you" button

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've already read this:
[Official reference for “don't leave ‘thank you’ comments”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101124/official-reference-for-dont-leave-thank-you-comments)

Some comments are not very helpful because all they say is: thanks. The system could detect this word in the comment (and other sentences like "thank you", "ty", etc) and suggest the commenter to click on the thanks button, instead. This button would be semantically different from the upvote button, in that it would mean that the question was not particularly helpful, but the commenter wants to thank the answerer.

Thanks-votes may or may not contribute to one's reputation.

Comment: So if we don't care for "thank you" in the comments, why in the world would we want a "thank you" button that would simply add the same useless noise? We say thanks with upvotes and checkmarks. That's the way we roll.

Comment: Why? What's the point. Can't we simply assume that the OP is thankful for any offered help and be done with it?

Comment: Why do I want to thank an answerer that wasn't particularly helpful to me?

Comment: @Matt maybe it was helpful to me, not the question itself. it is different.

Comment: I just don't understand how/why this is different than the upvote button. Do you not have the reputation to upvote yet?

Comment: How about a "Donate" button while we're at it?  Screw the upvote, send me ten bucks.  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, after 34 downvotes so far, that the thank you button has been implemented and released.

[image]

Comment: So far it is only on [so]. More details can be found on their meta: [Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367).

Comment: Where is the 138 from? Possibly from the question in question? From when it was -138?

Comment: Huh. A feature that was highly disliked by the community got implemented anyway. I wonder if there is a gap between the community and the executive team at SE.

Answer (score 33):

The best thank you is an upvote

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.  /s

Comment: Followed by an accept ;)

Comment: upvote means "useful/good answer", not "thank you".

Comment: @vulkanino Would you thank someone for any other reason?  Would you upvote something you found useful and call that being "ungrateful"?  They're exactly the same thing.  As an aside: The best thank you is recurring +500 bounties, not an upvote :P

Comment: Sweet sweet bounties

Answer (score 27):

A "thank you" is supposedly implicit, unless you make an habit, even in real life, to say "screw you" to whoever takes time to help you.

Moreover, SE network is a Q&A network.
It's not a forum.
It's not facebook.
It's not reddit.
It's not youtube.

You find an answer useful? Upvote it (as the message box suggests you when you hover the vote button). 

Does it solve your problem? Mark it as "accepted".

Anything else is a contamination from other environments where such things as "Like", "bump", "love" or whatnot may work.

Many are already frustrated by users who don't accept answers (cf. "accept rate" remarks), or who just say "thank you" after a solution and then disappear. I doubt that giving them a legitimate button for that will be a positive addition to a system that already is working at its best from 3 years.

Answer (score -9):

In my opinion, what's missing in these aggressive "we don't need a thank you / like / whatever bullshit" comments is acknowledging that in some cultures, it's polite to thank for help, and when asking a question and somebody takes some time to write down a nice answer, some people feel obliged to say thank you.

I think being thankful is not such a terrible thing that it deserve such harsh criticism.

And I like the idea to offer a separate button for this, as it would collect this kind of "noise" and put it somewhere else.

Could be a counter somewhere where people can see how many people have thanked them, but who doesn't bother won't be disturbed by this, and especially not receive notifications about "thank you" comments.

Yeah, I know they shouldn't be made, but welcome to reality, people make them anyways and always will. Because humans are diverse, and maybe it would be nice to open up for diversity a bit and not only support what white angry men think is appropriate interaction (sorry for the rant).

In the end, everyone would profit: The comments stay clean from personal stuff like "thank you", "+1" or "that helped me too!!!", users can express gratitude if they want to, the ones that don't care about it will be bothered less by notifications - to me, it's a win-win-win situation.

You could even display a hint for unexperienced users that press "thank you" without upvoting (or accepting the answer) first, where you ask them if they don't want to "upvote and thank" at the same time...

I wouldn't be surprised if that also results in more upvotes, because I can imagine not everyone is aware what upvotes are for.