# Should we flag comments that only praise an answer?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I'm sure we've all seen many comments that look like this:

> I'd +2 this answer if I could. Very helpful
>   +1, this is an awesome answer!
>   OMG, thank you so much, great answer!
>   I wish I could give 100 upvotes to this!

It always gives a nice warm feeling to have people acknowledge the quality of your answers. But do these comments contribute anything useful, or are they just noise that should be flagged?

**EDIT:** I am asking *only* about comments that do nothing but praise an answer. I am not concerned about comments that have more content in them, like these

> +1 for {specific reason}
>   The part about {reference to post content} is the best explanation I've seen about {topic}.

I think these are fine since they give the answerer good specific positive feedback. Celebratory comments that have no explanation, on the other hand, don't provide any more information than upvotes do, but they take up more space.

Comment: They are an additional indication that the answer was helpful.

Comment: I'd say they are just noise. You could flag them as *too chatty*. But I actually never do that.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: In my opinion this is the very small corner of social interaction in a rather very barren land. I'd say let them be, the time spent on flagging them is better be spent on helping by posting new answers or new helpful comments.

Comment: @Oded But not useful.  They are noise as you use upvotes to indicate whether or not a post is *useful* (as per the voting tooltip).  [They also don't fit any of the criteria for using comments either](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).  Therefore, they should be deleted.  To answer the question, *yes* flag them.

Comment: I want to express my appreciation for the meta meta jokes in here.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Actually, I'm disappointed...I expected a whole sh\*\*storm of "+1 great question!" comments...

Comment: Who said "a nice warm feeling" is not useful? It's probably a driving factor for many things we do in our lives, and if it leads to more questions getting answered, then I'd say great! :)

Comment: You should probably add `Your Welcome` since its the [2nd most common comment after what have you tried](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/106491/most-common-comments)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter To be fair, you usually need some kind of "thanks" comment before a "your welcome" comment gets posted :)

Comment: I like it when people tell me that it helped solved their problem. An upvote doesn't necessarily convey that

Comment: @AlEverett Great Meta-comment!

Comment: @Rachel I was only being half serious. I actually categorized the first 100 from that query so I could get a better idea of what the distribution was for identical comments. [Thanks is twice as common](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38edd/1) as your welcome

Comment: If I may humbly add, you guys are all splendid. OP you too.

Comment: @0A0D - Agreed, especially when there was back-&-forth to get to the solution.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that comments are rather small on the screen in proportion to the answers, people can easily skip them if they want to miss the social interactions that occur within them

Comment: The only reason I asked this question was to see the meta-humor "Great question!!" comments.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate to the linked question, and am voting to reopen. This question asks "Should I flag positive comments" while the linked question asks if +1 comments are necessary and has two relevant answers: the top voted one of *"I like to give a reason for my upvotes often times to give more context. If you don't like them don't read them"*, and the moderator one saying *"I don't like them either and we've added a flag reason for them"*. This question seems like a followup to the linked post, not a duplicate.

Comment: So... it's been reopened by the MSO community and closed a 2nd time by a moderator as a duplicate to another closed-as-duplicate question (which I think is answered worse than this one ;)), and *that* duplicate doesn't answer this question either? I guess MSO doesn't like your question Peter :)

Answer (score 22):

I would not flag them unless there becomes a lot of them and they start to overshadow other more important comments

- In most cases, they aren't doing any harm by being there
- Upvotes can have multiple meanings, and as [Oded said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175150/should-we-flag-comments-that-only-praise-an-answer#comment524699_175150), they're an additional indication that the answer was helpful, and not just upvoted based on some other meaning.

  I have seen upvotes mean many things, ranging from *"+1 for the effort"* to *"+1 for pointing me in the right direction"* to *"+1 for pointing out some related fact, even though this doesn't answer the question"*. Because of that, I do not always trust upvotes to mean "good answer" or "this answer is correct for the question asked", and will often trust an answer more if it has a highly upvoted *"+1 great answer!"* comment on it.
- The removal of such comments could be disruptive to the community as people start asking "why did my comment go missing"
- They provide a more "human" element to the community.  I'm sure not everyone is the same, but I personally like seeing comments like that, and knowing people's reactions to my posts. It keeps me coming back to answer more questions and help more users.
- A large number of people participate in the SE communities because they *are* a community, and you'd alienate them if you start stamping out all basic human interactions, leaving only the encyclopedic information

And last of all in response to

> It always gives a nice warm feeling to have people acknowledge the quality of your answers. But do these comments contribute anything useful?

Who said "a nice warm feeling" is not useful? It's probably a driving factor for many things we do in our lives, and if it leads to more questions getting answered, then I'd say great! :)

Comment: "Positive human interactions" are explicitly captured in the upvote and accept answer functionality.  To allow *all* forms of positive human interactions on the site would be detrimental, as it would lead to too much noise.

Comment: @casperOne Sorry, I disagree with your first sentence. Seeing a number increase is not a "human interaction". There are many users that participate because they want to "give back" to the community or want to simply help other users out. They participate in the SE communities because they're a *community*. Don't get rid of that. (But I do agree that *all* forms of human interactions would be detrimental. We don't need "how are you today" comments on posts)

Comment: @casperOne Surely there is a difference between allowing *"all forms of positive human interactions"* and the occasional comment showing appreciation. If I see something devolve into a mess of off-topic/chatty comments, I'll be the first to flag or ask for a cleanup. But I don't see harm in a single such comment. (Even when it's admittedly not what this site is for).

Comment: The value-add for the Stack Exchange sites isn't in the users, it's in the content.  Just saying.

Comment: @Bart I'm not saying that one should go on a snipe hunt for these kinds of comments (although I'd personally like for a way to more easily do this) but rather, if you see it, flag it.  Comments of the form "+/- <here is some really relevant information>" are ok, they just have the little smudge of the "+/-" at the beginning.  They shouldn't be removed.  It's the "+1 this is great" kind of stuff that should go.  If you see it, it's not asking too much that you flag it.

Comment: @Bart It also gives a confusing impression of the site when you see that "+1 this helped me so much" comment upvoted 44 times but the answer that it's attached to only upvoted twice.

Comment: @casperOne True. Then we more or less agree.

Comment: @casperOne I end up seeing it more with downvotes.  "-1 XYZ is wrong" will often get tons of upvotes, but only one or two downvote the question (because they don't want to lose their 1 rep I guess?).

Comment: @casperOne I look forward to the day when I see comments that read *Comments are for clarification, constructive criticism or minor or transient information only. See the [comment privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) and this [meta question for more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175150)*

Comment: 'The removal of such comments could be disruptive to the community as people start asking "why did my comment go missing"' - That's makes absolutely no sense at all. Every moderation action can be disruptive to the community, we can't stop moderating the site in fear someone will complain.

Comment: @Yannis Compare that to the impact of just leaving the comment alone. Who is it harming? Who is it bothering? You'll note that in the very first line I said "I would not flag *unless they start overshadowing other more important comments*", which is the only situation in which I think those comments would be bothersome.

Comment: @Rachel They are setting a bad example that pointless comments are ok.

Comment: @Rachel You don't know if the comment contains useful information until after you read it.  Even if there is no other useful information, if the comment wasn't there then people not there is no information to add.  If it is there they're spending time reading comments that aren't helpful to them.

Comment: @Yannis *we can't stop moderating the site in fear someone will complain* Yes but the assumption is that moderation adds more value then the disruption. I personally don't think that the "noise" generated by `+1 thanks` aren't high enough to warrant the downsides.

Comment: @Servy I don't know about you, but it doesn't take any time at all for my brain to process or skip past a short comment like *"+1 great answer!"* :)

Comment: @Rachel It takes very little time, not "no time at all".  Multiply that by the number of users reading through it, and then all of the posts that it happens on, and it becomes a not so little amount of time.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Personally, I won't go hunting for "+1 great answer" comments on either site I moderate, so I guess we don't really disagree on that. But if someone flags, I won't think twice before killing the comment.

Comment: @Yannis Not everyone has the same definition of "pointless comment". I don't find it pointless to read a "+1 great answer!" comment on a post where there is 3 answers, each with a score of 1. I also don't find it pointless when someone leaves a comment on my answers thanking me for my time. SE is a Q&A *community*, not a Q&A Encyclopedia or Reference Manual.

Comment: @Rachel and it appears that not everyone has the same definition of "community" either...

Comment: @Yannis I'm not sure where you're getting your definition from, but my definition matches [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community): *Community usually refers to a social unit larger than a small village that shares common values.* SE sites are built and run by a community of users who share an interested in a topic, and not by a series of search bots that can read a reference manual and filter content based on an Regex.

Comment: Well, that's a good definition, no argument there. That killing "+1 comments" translates to "aa series of search bots that can read a reference manual and filter content based on an Regex" is just your opinion though @Rachel.

Comment: "SE is a Q&A community" - That's never been the case.  It's a Q&A *site* which communities form around.

Comment: @Servy: " Multiply that by the number of users" - talk about premature optimization! :-) `Cumulative wasted time (measured in fractions of a second) * number of global potential readers = too much wasted time`???

Comment: I agree with this post - and.. courtesy  never hurt anyone. Can you go too far? Perhaps, but I've never seen anybody asking "what'd ya have for breakfast Sir?" in the comments.

Comment: I think that these comments are good. It's really a boost to keep on answering when I see someone say that I really helped them. Much more so that 25 rep, which is the most one person can give me (usually, ignoring bounties). It really encourages people to stay around and answer more.

Comment: @casperOne: That's silly. Everybody knows SE is a *company* that specializes in making Q&A sites around which communities form.

Comment: **"The value-add for the Stack Exchange sites isn't in the users, it's in the content. Just saying. – casperOne♦"** - Wow. Just wow. With moderators sharing attitudes like this one, I understand why SO has been so [dehumanizing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/set-up-an-archive-for-legendary-deleted-questions) lately. Though I don't understand why said expendable users aren't [left alone to create value-adding content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214385/how-does-meteor-work/).

Answer (score 5):

If you want, wait for the OP to see them before flagging. But yes, you can flag these as "too chatty". Comments are only for stuff which may result in an improvement to the post.

However, these aren't too problematic unless there are too many of them. I just leave them alone. On sites I moderate, I delete old ones when I come across them, but I don't go actively looking for comments to delete.

Comment: You _don't_ go actively looking for comments to delete??? Please turn in your diamonds _immediately_.

Answer (score 5):

I'd ignore a single one of those, especially if the comment is from the user that asked the question. Of course an upvote or accepting the answer carries the same information, so those comments are redundant. But getting rid of them is probably more trouble than it is worth if they are the only comment on an answer.

Quite some new users also don't upvote or accept answers, so the comment might be the only indication that it solved the problem for the asker. And if the comment contains some actual information behind the +1, it should of course also not be deleted.

Comment flags are not easily handled by 10k users because there is no 10k+ queue for them, so they would have to be handled by diamond moderators. But flagging them is also not wrong, so if you want you can go ahead and do that.

I'd certainly flag them if there are many comments on the answer, or even multiple of these +1 comments. In those cases they drown out other, potentially more useful comments.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a single one, just leave it be. It might be an additional useful indicator of the post's quality.

If it attracts tons of such comments however, you could flag the later ones.

Comment: +1, this is an awesome answer!

Comment: I'm amazed how many people went the "they help indicate good answers" route with this; how is upvoting not sufficient for that? If the site wanted you to upvote an answer twice it would let you; comments are clearly not for this

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I have seen upvotes mean many things, ranging from *"+1 for the effort"* to *"+1 for pointing me in the right direction"* to *"+1 for pointing out some related fact, even though this doesn't answer the question"*. Because of that, I do not always trust upvotes to mean "good answer" or "this answer is correct for the question asked"

Comment: @Rachel Then people need to stop using upvotes wrong; I shouldn't need to read the whole comment tree to decipher why a post has 5 upvotes -- it should mean 5 people think it's the right answer

Comment: @MichaelMrozek If the comment is a mere "+1 great answer", then I would agree. Just upvote. There are however comments pointing out another positive aspect of a post which do not necessarily translate into an upvote, or do not just translate into an upvote. I see no harm in such comments, if not used excessively.

Comment: @Bart Yes, and this question is specifically about "comments that only praise an answer", with a bunch of examples that don't point out other positive aspects. I can live with "+1 because your explanation of {one particular part} was really good", I don't like "+1 because you made me smile", and I can't believe there's even an argument about just "+1"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Hmm, I see I have not stayed close to the question asked in my thoughts and motivations about it. I think we actually have pretty much the same view.

Answer (score 1):

I won't address whether they should be removed (or flagged for removal) but only the closely related question of whether they should be posted in the first place. No: *except* where the one commenting is the question's asker and he's commenting on an answer. (In other words, *those* comments should be not only not deleted/flagged but posted initially, though I have no comment on the deletability/flaggability of other such comments (though they should not be posted).)

An upvote is anonymous and there's no way except comments (and acceptance, which I'll get to in a moment) to know which answer or answers match the asker's intent, especially for a possibly ambiguous or broad question. (Of course, questions *shouldn't* be ambiguous or to-broad, but that doesn't mean they *aren't*.) And acceptance (the checkmark) doesn't substitute for a comment, as (a) it can be applied to at most one answer, and sometimes more than one is acceptable and (b) sometimes no answer fully answers the question, so the asker doesn't wish to accept any, but one or more were helpful.

Comment: "I won't address whether they should be removed (or flagged for removal)". I'm trying to decide if I should just flag this NaA now, or finish reading it first

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, better now?

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of comments give legitimacy to the answer in a way that simple upvoting does not.  Upvoting is critical in is own ways, but I would use an answer with these kinds of comments over a similarly-upvoted answer  that doesn't have these kinds of comments.

Keep them and don't flag them.