# Thank you to another comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, ethics

I know its not recommended to leave a pure "Thank you" comment for a good answer, but if I have posted the answer, and someone's comment for my answer
   is useful, can I (besides up-voting the comment) to post a thank
   you comment to show my acknowledgement?

I'm asking because I have forced myself (by looking at the watermark in the comment box) to not say thank you and instead upvoted the comment, but later see other user act in the other way...

Comment: The upvote is a thank you, because it provided something useful presumably

Comment: @RGraham, yes that's what I was thinking, the only problem is that the commenter won't know if that was you (up-voting)

Comment: I always feel a bit awkward when I can't say "thank you". It's a nice thing to do and it promotes good feeling between people.

Comment: @Bolu I think that's a good thing. I like the way that Stack Overflow has anonymous voting. Prevents clutter like "@RGraham Why no thanks??" and other such comments.

Comment: I'm surprised we don't have more "Upvoters, please comment!" comments. :)

Comment: @Wooble, I do agree up-voting is enough in most cases, but since a good comment for your answer is normally pointing out something you are missing, and if you don't comment anything, although there could be alot up-votes for that comment (to say this is good), the commenter will still have the feeling that you (the author of the answer) may not agree with his comment.

Comment: If somebody posts a usefull comment I would say the best thing to do is take their point from the comment and edit your post to refer to the comment. It would acknowledge their contribution, and it also saves the information being lost if through some circumstance the comment is removed.

Comment: Presumably you could include the comment within your answer, and them reply to them informing them of that fact, technically (if we're getting all lawyery) you could be inviting them to delete their comment as it is now obsolete. Edit @Amber Great minds clearly think alike

Comment: The best that can happen is "Thank you for your input, updated my question" when previous comment provided some more details ;) And in reply like that, adding "Glad I helped" does not hurt anyone.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169994/should-a-thank-you-comment-be-flagged?rq=1

Comment: We can't even use comments to comment on how well the answer served us?  I know I haven't been around much, but *this is way beyond ridiculous.* Sounds like something has been lodged so far up that it'll be impossible to remove now though...

Comment: @AdamDavis: See the accepted answer on the duplicate question.

Answer (score 9):

It's perfectly fine to leave thank you comments.  Just don't expect them to be a permanent fixture on the site.  Over time, such comments tend to get removed to reduce noise, and that's as it should be, since the comment has already served its purpose.