# What is wrong with the way I'm asking this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question here: [What is the most recent version of GAE SDK that supports Python 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139793/which-versions-of-gae-sdk-support-python-2-5)

I got no upvotes, and I got two comments, both of which indicated that their writers had not read the body of my question, which was short, and as far as I can tell, was clear.

Is there something wrong with my question?
Or wrong with the way I'm asking it?

Comment: No upvotes is no reason for alarm. Give it some time, I've had a couple questions go unnoticed for weeks, without anything ostensibly wrong with them.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Stack Overflow is no research assistent. It is off-topic.

Comment: @juergend Please clarify how it is off topic.

Comment: @juergend The question doesn't appear off-topic, and its wording appears to be reasonably simple and concise.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool ...* close reason.

Comment: @juergend I don't see how that applies at all.

Comment: @juergend There is no recommendation.  There is a single, provably correct answer to the question.  Only one possible version of one possible tool is a valid answer.

Comment: @tom As of now, you got 6 upvotes.

Comment: This is one of the reasons we shouldn't call the site-specific close reasons "off-topic". juergen has put the words recommend and "off-topic" together to make a rule that says that questions about tools are off-topic. SE has extended the phrase off-topic to any close reason that's site-specific; you put that together with the everyday understanding of off-topic and you get a serious over-generalisation of a rule which is essentially about library shopping against a question which is purely factual. Libraries etc are on-topic for SO, library recommendations are disallowed, not off-topic. @Servy

Comment: @AndrewC: "*library recommendations are disallowed, not off-topic.*" I fail to see the distinction between "disallowed" and "off-topic". We "disallow" questions about fishing too. Why? Because this isn't a site for fishing questions. Just like this isn't a site for library recommendation questions. I fail to see how changing "off-topic" to "disallowed" would make *any difference* to this misunderstanding. His problem is that he confused "library recommendation" with "anything about libraries", not that he confused "off-topic" with something else.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was continuing a debate from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086). In ordinary English usage, off-topic may imply disallowed, but they mean different things. Only on Stack Exchange are these two concepts confused. Changing the wording won't _prevent_ generalisation, but using the word topic _encourages_ it.  Elsewhere on the internet, the conversation we're having now in these comments would be described as off-topic (we're not discussing the OP's Q), but that's not what SE means by off-topic just now. It's a misnomer just like Not Constructive was.

Comment: @NicolBoras My guess that you were a seasoned user that had probably known the new close reasons for a while seems correct. I said redefining the phrase off-topic would lead to misapplication of the subreasons; it' happening. Unless the headline _and_ the subtext are literally true, it'll be like Too Localized and Not Constructive. Fix it with a small amount of editing while the reasons are still young and before they've got warped too far! If we don't, we'll just need another massive overhaul in a year or two. You fix bugs early, while everything's still fresh, to reduce the work it takes.

Comment: Remember that the subtext for Not Constructive was pretty clear and fairly accurate? .....like the wording for the new subreasons of the inaccurately named off-topic. I challenge you to find anyone who doesn't use stack-exchange who thinks that the best description for a question which asks for code but which doesn't show minimal understanding is "off-topic", unless you explain why that counts as off-topic or otherwise prepare/convince them.

Comment: @AndrewC: "*I was continuing a debate from here.*" But what does that debate have to do with anything going on *here*? You can argue whether questions that don't provide enough information should be considered "off topic". But that's not what's we're talking about; we're talking about *library recommendation* questions, which very much are "off topic" by any reasonable definition of that term. We're explicitly saying that, while they are about code and programming, they are not acceptable topics for questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Because it's precisely the generalisation encouraged by the use of the word topic. _libraries & tools_ is a topic, a _request for a library/toolset recommendation_ is a question on the topic of _libraries & tools_, with the everyday meaning of the word. If you call it a topic, people, as happened here, will treat anything about libraries & toolsets as off-topic. However, the OP's question is allowed_*_ even though it's about the same topic as the questions we don't allow. That's the reasonable meaning of "topic", but you've already generalised/switched the meaning in your mind.

Comment: (_*_ since Robert Harvey, diamond mod, reopened it when I brought this problem up in the other question.)

Comment: To put it in stack exchange terminology, if it's a tag, that's what most people think is a topic. If it's a meta tag, people don't think that's a topic. "Libraries and tools" would be a fairly broad tag, but "recommendation" would get burninated as a meta-tag. It's the recommendation from a collection of possibilities with varying merits that's disallowed. Libraries and tools themselves are on-topic.

Comment: People will understandably attach the off-topic to the topic part of the "library recommmendation" bit - libraries, not the question type/meta tag bit, _because_ that's what topic refers to, but it's the recommendation from list part that's not welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there's anything *wrong* with your post but I can speculate on why (before now) it did not get much attention:

- It's only tagged `[google-app-engine]`, so only people with knowledge in that area are likely to view it. I'm not saying to add more tags, but if there are any more that you think would apply, you can retag it for a bit more visibility.
- It was only asked 17 hours ago, so not too many people have had the chance to see it. Not only that, but it was asked at 4am (my time) which is generally slow on SO.

Also note that lack of upvotes does not indicate a problem with the question.

Some other tips; In your comment you noted:

> I need to be able to use both 2.5 and 2.7

This is essential info that should be in the post body. Edit it in. Editing also bumps your question to the front page which means more visibility. However, don't abuse this feature.

Your original version:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18139793/1

Don't add greetings, taglines, "thanks", or signatures to posts, see:

- [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)
- [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

As far as the 2 comments go, they probably did not read your question properly. It happens all the time. People first see the question title, and often dive in with a comment or answer ready to post, but don't take the time to read the details. It's not your fault, but as Servy said - if there's *anything* you can do to clarify your post you should do it.

Comment: thanks! (I'm allowed to thank in a comment, right? Or is that frowned on ?)

Comment: @tom http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 6):

I agree with those saying that your question is concise, clear and easy to understand.

However, one thing I noticed was the title. It is the only part of the question visible to people who access SO from the front page, and hence to a large degree what makes or breaks the question.

You can even say that many users will decide whether (and how) to answer a question based on the title. The body is just fluff. The psychological chain of reasoning follows more or less this pattern:

1. I want to show the world how brilliant I am (i.e., I want to re-affirm to myself how brilliant I am).
2. Let me find a question that is either deep enough to let me show off my superior knowledge or misguided enough to let me show the asker the error of his ways, thereby cementing my position as a knowledgeable person. It has to be a question with no or very few answers already, or my mentoring will drown in the noise.
3. Ah! there was one - someone looking for an old software version when a new and shining one is available.
4. I'll tell him that in a firm voice which underscores my natural leadership skills and up-to-date technical knowledge, so we don't risk turning this into an argument.
5. Let me skim the question just to be sure - yes: *blah, blah, migrating*, *blah, blah, not supported*. Nothing of importance here. I'm good to go!
6. Click "Post Your Answer".

The title frames the understanding of the question, the same way a headline in a newspaper provides the frame in which the article is decoded. I *think* the psychological theory of "framing" is a useful key to understand how the title influences people's reading of the question, but I am more than willing to be corrected if someone has better references than my patchy memory.

Add to this the time pressure. The FGITW problem means that you have to answer quickly, and if your mind is convinced that it has understood the problem (through the framing effect mentioned earlier), actually reading the full body of the question just seems like a way to waste precious time in the race to answer first.

If I understand your question correctly, you need to migrate an app from an earlier version of Python to the current one, and you have already decided that you need the older one for that.  Hence, this is what you ask, quite reasonably, but in this specific case you might have obtained better answers if you had not already pointed at the solution - but that is just a guess, and SO doesn't allow for A/B testing of questions (or their titles).

Comment: I can't decide if this is a brilliant psychological observation, or a rant cleverly disguised as a brilliant psychological observation.  Did you apply this thought process when you looked at this question and decided to answer it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I really believe that there is a strong framing effect in showing only the titles on the front page. The "cost" of changing page to the question means that one must have decided from the title that it will be worthwhile clicking on the question, and I believe that one will also have created a picture in one's mind of what to expect - and what to answer if there is not _strong_ evidence showing that the initial impression was wrong. The ranty aspect is just my amateurish literary skills. And being psychological effects, I don't know myself if I was being influenced by them :-)

Answer (score -5):

> and as far as I can tell, was clear.

Well, considering the two people who commented misunderstood it, we have observational evidence that it's *not* clear.  Consider rephrasing the question to avoid this.  Even if *you* think it's clear, and some others do as well, doesn't mean you can't also find a slightly different wording that even more people also find clear.

Or you could just ignore the people that didn't understand it and wait for an answer from someone who thinks your question is clear as it is.  (While this suggestion may seem sarcastic, it is not.)

Comment: I don't see how the question could be clearer. People very often just read the question title and not the body (very common and very annoying).

Comment: @WesleyMurch Hence my second paragraph.

Comment: Perhaps you did not read the post as well....

Comment: @WesleyMurch What gives you that indication?  Perhaps you didn't read this post as well...

Comment: Your leading paragraph gave me that indication. It's generic advice. The question is pretty much as to-the-point as possible.

Comment: The question doesn't say that the SDK needs to support both 2.5 and 2.7. It's established only in the comments. It's not unreasonable to say that the question can be misunderstood.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes, it is generic advice.  Why answer the case of just this one question when I can answer the case of this problem in general, which also covers the case of this one question.  It also has the advantage of making this post useful to future visitors, rather than just being localized to this one user.  When doing so is complex or otherwise unfeasible, I don't, but when it's easy, I try to do so.

Comment: I understand @Servy, but it's good to address the specific case at hand. In this case I would speculate that the lack of attention is because the question has low views, and only one fairly niche tag, and that the two comments simply did not read the post properly.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Despite having looked through the specific case several times, I don't really see much more that I could add that is specific to this question.  He could choose to re-word the question, in the attempt to improve it, if he wanted, or he can trust that future readers will understand it as is.  I certainly don't think that it would be *wrong* to try to improve it, so trying to say something along the lines of "don't change anything" wouldn't be productive.

Comment: @WesleyMurch It's worth noting, in general, that a post can be phrased such that it has a higher or lower probability of being read properly.  Yes, if you read it carefully, it's quite obvious what's going on, and that the comments make no sense.  This happens a lot, I agree, but re-wording of a question can, potentially, make it more likely that someone that reads a question less carefully still understand enough.  This has to do with things like choosing what information to put in the most-read spots, such as the title, first sentence, last sentence, etc.

Comment: Also the side effect of bumping the post after an edit of course is helpful. I can't say whether or not it would be proper to add the python tag.

Comment: Side note: I see a lot of people guarding against the inevitability of someone misunderstanding their post by using loud disclaimers. **"DONT SUGGEST JQUERY BECAUSE I CANT USE IT!! THE QUESTION IS NOT TAGGED JQUERY"** I get the feeling that "rep hunters" often don't read the question properly (you have to act fast to win FGITW). I've had this happen to me quite a few times and seen it a lot, where they answer the question title verbatim ignoring the important details in the post body.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yeah, I've actually stopped editing that out (only toning it down when it's in all caps). Much as I hate to admit it, this is a pretty widespread problem.

Comment: Good thing we have a downvote button for those answers that are irrelevant to the question, right guys? Seriously, that's a way better solution than adding a bunch of unnecessary noise to the question.