# How do I thank someone for a helpful edit to my post?

Tags: support, edits, thanks

Sometimes, someone edits my posts. The edits were very helpful, so I want to thank them.

How do I thank someone for a helpful edit to my post? Adding a comment, or something else?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks are not expected for editing. I suspect that simply accepting them rather than rolling them back will be all that editors want.

Using the occasional comment to thank should do no great harm but I recommend not doing it often and, when you do, be specific about what you are thanking them for.

A comment that says little more than thanks has no value.

Comment: I agree. Thanking the editor in a comment may be okay, especially when the editor goes up and beyond doing a few grammatical corrections and genuinely improves the post, which could cost the editor more than a couple of minutes in doing so.

Answer (score 13):

[@ notifications can also be used to ping editors](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/255554). So a comment can make the editor aware of your gratefulness. As already stated, this is not the intended purpose of comments, but you can always delete the comment after a while, when you think it reached its target.

As there is no mechanism to reward outstanding edits with extra reputation, I do not consider it a problem if the editor is at least rewarded with some verbal praise in a comment. By contrast, thanking people for questions and answers is much less called for as there are mechanisms for this (votes and bounties).

An alternative to leaving a comment is checking whether the editor is active in the site’s chatrooms and contact them there.

Answer (score 8):

There's no need to thank editors.

You can comment on the post and @reply to the editor and they [will be notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/307988), but "Thank you"s [aren't what comments are meant for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/307988) so don't be offended if it is flagged and removed.