# Is there any way to thank editors of my questions?

Tags: support, edits, thanks

I recently asked a handful of questions. Since my native language isn't English some of my text isn't on par with what some users are used to reading.

While I always try to learn from other users' edits I never found an option/way to thank them. Even though this might seem irrelevant I somehow feel the need to do so.

Is there any option to do so?

Comment: See [How can I acknowledge, thank, or otherwise approve of an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142142/289905) and [How do I thank someone for a helpful edit to my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294992/289905).