# Feature to address the "Thanks" + "You're welcome" protocol without leaving comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

There [must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28763087/314291) [be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762604/314291) [millions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762032/314291) of Posts where a question is answered, and either the OP, or a `Me Too` poster responds with a comment of "Thanks" (in addition to, or instead of the correct practice of upvoting and / or ticking the answered check).

And social etiquette may then also result in a ["You're Welcome"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421896/314291) response to the "Thanks" comment (and [even chastising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31554490/314291) of said comments).

This is just human nature to do so, and makes SO a friendly place, although as per previous discussions this isn't one of the intended [purpose of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145551/acknowledging-thank-you-comments) - in fact, its [against the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

If I do receive a "Thanks" comment on a question I've answered, I've fallen into the habit of [Upvoting the "Thanks" comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31339881/314291), and in many cases the OP / Me Too will then recognize this as an acknowledgement of `You're welcome` and then tidy up the question by deleting his/her original "Thanks" comment, and all is good in the world.

But sadly, this isn't always the case.

<del>So **TL;DR** Would a feature be useful in order whereby this "Thanks" / "Your Welcome" etiquette can be formalized and allow for the "Social" aspects of the exchange, privately between the two parties without clogging up the comments?

Something perhaps like this:

![Thanks / Youre Welcome][1]

With a corresponding notification to the other party, and the ability to then acknowledge the "Thanks", all done behind the scenes in private.

These Thanks / Welcome exchanges have no bearing on rep etc (although I guess there's always a WinterBash opportunity in there somewhere)</del>

**Edit**

Well I guess that idea didn't go down very well. I do see Martijn's point about the problem that answers would now attract "thanks" instead of votes.

As an alternative, then, how about more comment filters, blocking `Thanks` comments and encouraging the use of voting instead?. For instance :[image: No thanks]. Somehow, the "Thanks / Welcome" comments seem to be in a grey limbo area - it would seem rude to ban them but at the same time they really don't add any value.

**Edit #2**

Another idea possibly would be to allow a comment to be marked (by its poster, or I guess the weight of the community) as 'chirpy' or 'social', and it would be auto-deleted within say 24 hours. This should leave sufficient time for the social protocol to be met, and then as time passes the question / answer will return to a more pristine condition. Possibly filters can assist in automating or prompting here.

Comment: If you want to thank someone for a helpful post, you *vote the post up*. Adding a 'say thanks' button means people will use that instead of voting. There really is **no point** in such a button.

Comment: Well, perhaps then add a flag on a comment which basically says "Retract your Thanks comment"? But now we are clogging up the moderation queues.

Comment: Just flag as *Too chatty*. We blast through those in 10 minutes anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it is useful. Accepting and up-voting are enough message to me the answer was helpful. Why need a *thank you* message if you have those?

I see no use in this feature. How would it feel to receive a *thanks* without up-vote? I think this will only confuse users more.

---

I do like your second proposal: educating new users how to use their votes. This would really be beneficial to the site and every user.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that most of the *thanks* comments I've seen were from users who never upvoted that very answer; in other words, adding noise like that mostly comes from users who don't know **how** to say thanks. . .

Comment: I'm guessing I wasn't really making my point clearly - apologies - I was trying to find a polite way to prevent / avoid chatty comments by upholding [principles such as this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/314291). And it just feels morally wrong flagging "thanks" / "welcome" comments. Getting no (rep) recognition for good answers is something we [just](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31265482/314291) [need](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31262677/314291) to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an affirm argument you may not have thought about:

Imagine a question that has 40+ answers. Sure, they're ranked by number of votes, so one would assume the top ranked answers are the better answers of the bunch. However, so many times you'll find a question asked in 2014 and the best answer is also from 2014.

In the world of programming, for example, that 2014 answer could be very well outdated, especially as new frameworks and standards are released over the years... so the proper 2018 answer might be buried on the second page; and that 2018 answer is what you really need to read.

Comments *under* an answer bring attention to that answer '**visually**'. Someone saying '*Wow, thanks so much for this!*' is much more telling (to me) than an answer that has 17 votes with no comments vs. an answer that has 16 votes with a single comment. I'm more likely to stop and read the answer that has a comment of '*This should be the accepted answer!*' comments versus an answer that has no discussion.

Therefore, I would argue that comments such as '*Thanks for this!*' should be allowed to stay on the site in moderation.

Food for thought.