# How do we thank the diamond moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators, thanks

Is there a way to do this?

I made a delete request yesterday and it was granted.  Wanted to express my appreciation.

I kind of just did what I wanted to do, but I fully understand that this is a question and answer site, and thanking a group of people isn't asking a question.

Comment: As of now all the moderators on the network are now feeling a little less harried and under-appreciated. *Mission accomplished.*

Comment: +1 because apparently this question doesn't exist anywhere on meta, I'm a little surprised.

Comment: Don't listen to @random! Get yourself suspended! We _love_ suspending people! :P

Comment: Also, this post probably wasn't directed towards me (I don't moderate any site you're active on), but it still made my day. Thanks! :D

Comment: This reminded me of [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=9038864#9038864): *I recall my days of tech support and all you hear are the complaints. One time I got a phone call from a customer and they said "Thank you, everything is working right. You guys probably don't hear that enough." -- and that was the entire call.*

Comment: I'd take a few unicorn dollars... :P

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Pay it forward.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101126/165773)

Anything from:

- Patrolling the various close and review queues with both eyes open
- Not dragging out comments
- Don't get into rollback wars
- Keeping your cool
- Don't do things that make them have to suspend your account

In short, continue on the path of a Stack Exchange citizen in good standing.

Comment: Exactly! If the only way we know of you is from your good flags and your activity here on Meta, we love you!

Comment: What do you mean by "not dragging out comments"?  (Forgive me if I just did it.)

Comment: @John: (It's OK to do it on meta, partly): Don't get into long discussions in the comments. Move it to chat at the first opportunity when you realize that the discussion may get lengthy.

Answer (score 12):

There's not any way to do that.  It's okay not to say thank you (because there's not any way to do that).  Just say it in your heart.

Keep in mind they deal with a big volume of requests, most of which are on the quick side.  Acknowledging thank you's would either be 1) superfluous or 2) time consuming enough to actually impact their ability to work through the moderation queue.  Keep in mind the point of even saying "thank you" when conducting business over the phone is to clearly say "I have no further business" all the moreso than to express gratitude, and that etiquette doesn't add value in this context.

If you really want to thank the moderator anyway, SE doesn't have private message channels.  You could reach out to the moderator personally, if they have their email or site posted on their profile (most do I think).  I'm taking neutral stance on recommending or suggesting this - if a moderator's contact info is there it's presumably so people can use their own judgment in contacting them, and thanking someone for something trivial could come across as any of ignorant or annoying, poignant and human, or perhaps be the lead you need to go into business together some day.  That's what networking is, and it's not my business to say whether you should or whether we encourage this; it's just a physical option you have.

Comment: I have no idea of the volume of requests they deal with; it could be huge.  It could have been one of 200 delete requests he did that day and he looked at it for under a minute.  But he still did me a great favor by getting rid of an exchange that reflected a lapse of judgment on my part.  I don't even know which one it was, and I don't even need acknowledgement.  But they're human, and showed compassion, and it was appreciated.