# When can someone show gratitude on this site for things a person has done (not necessarily on this site)?

Tags: discussion, meta, asking-questions, off-topic, thanks

I have read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342079/thank-you-robert-cartaino) question. It doesn't seem like a question to me; it looks more like a comment one can put below questions and answers.

I thought one should avoid comments (assuming this question is a comment) like this. Of course, this doesn't mean it's **impossible** to make comments that express these feelings of gratitude (I like them very much). I couldn't find an answer to my question in the provided information (given by the site).

In which cases these feelings of gratitude can be made (in the form of a question)?

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180579/how-do-we-thank-the-diamond-moderators) question is somewhat similar but received 35 upvotes.

Comment: _“comments (questions)”_, _“ask questions (make comments)”_ — are you aware that comments and questions are completely different things? Meta Stack Exchange is also not a “main site” for a specific subject, where, indeed, “thank you” **comments** should be avoided, but _also_ “thank you” **questions**.

Comment: Of course I'm aware! What I meant is that the question **looks** like a comment. Which you can put below a question or an answer. But I'll edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How do we thank the diamond moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180579/how-do-we-thank-the-diamond-moderators)

Comment: @descheleschilder Also note that Meta sites have a tradition to say _farewell_ or _thank you_ using questions. IMO these could be understood as announcements of such events, and are usually well received, even if these aren't quesitons.

Comment: These are rare cases of using the platform to say goodbye. Yes, strictly speaking it's off topic but it's allowed in those rare cases. Consider it a non written rule.

Comment: It seems all my questions get closed on this site. While others take the benefit...

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It is a question on Meta asking about questions on Meta. Cannot get more Meta than that.

Comment: Maybe my comment should be avoided but nevertheless: That's a good one!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's a very good reference!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you linked to: "[Thank you, Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342079/thank-you-robert-cartaino)" is a thank you to a departing employee.

Technically (strictly) speaking [thank you comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145551/acknowledging-thank-you-comments) are against site policy; but many enjoy receiving them all the same. The *correct* procedure is an upvote, accept, or manually award a bounty to a specific answer. That post is quite different. Some have received an increase in their votes since leaving, I don't want to single someone out as they've asked not to be the face of this.

When a moderator or employee leaves or changes roles sometimes they or someone else will do a write-up, sometimes not. Recently a number of people have *left* / *retired* / quit or were fired - we appreciate their work over the years and look forward to hearing from them from time to time.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to thank someone for a good answer is to upvote it. The same for questions. Accepting a great answer to your question is also a good way to express gratitude. You can also assign bonuses if you've got enough rep.

The reason we don't expect thanks in comment / questions is that they're a distraction from the main purpose of this site, which is the Q&A themselves. I must admit, I found this difficult at first, because I'm from a culture where omitting verbal expressions of thanks (along with regret, etc.) is considered the height of bad manners. However, I've got used to the way things are done around here, and have come to appreciate its merits.

(Some people who still like to post thanks in comments. Whilst that isn't expected behaviour, it is understandable, so we don't make a big deal about it either way.)

The rare exceptions to the above are announcements about departing CMs, etc. But these *are* exceptions. It's a bit like when someone leaves a workplace - when that happens it is traditional to make a speech for them, and to collect money for a gift. But, that isn't what we do for people every day. Similarly, when a CM leaves the SO network, we express our gratitude by saying a big thank you. But day-to-day we just use upvotes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Meta is not a...usual site.

It's a little difficult to those uninitiated in its mysteries (but those are no secret), but fundamentally, it's a site *for* questions about the Stack Exchange network of sites. It's also, in a sense, a place for announcements, and other information that the community as a whole would be interested in.

Considering the...less than adequate manner of send off that our very much beloved former CMs got, the community stepped up in various ways.

Meta is where we talk about...the network. The network is community and people. When someone has gone over and beyond the call of duty, and helped bring...pretty much every site in the network today into being, or mentored basically every CM...

Well, they're something of importance to the community. As such, well, it belongs here.