# The FAQ page should have a prominent link to the About page

Tags: feature-request, site-faq, tour

- The About page is designed to be the "[QuickStartening](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/)" point for new users to (hopefully) grok Stack Exchange painlessly
- The FAQ is the longer form, rather complete cheatsheet with more details and verbiage about most aspects of the site.
- When a user sees his post deleted, SE adds a note to check the FAQ to understand why this happened. Most of the time, it's because you answered with a comment, a question, an edit or something.

This means that if a new user skips the About page, skips the FAQ, posts a comment in the answer box and checks back, he'll be linked to the "old, boring" FAQ, and not the new and hip StackExchange QuickStartening Aboutinator.

This suggests a rather simple change to fix this "user story":

[image: "New user? Start here!"]

Comment: I fully agree. In fact, I agree so much that I even have an existing meta proposal for this: [Create a page specifically designed for new users, and link to it at the top of the faq?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132833/158605). It got marked as [status-completed] with the new about page, but only the first part was done :)

Comment: Perhaps we could have a rep requirement for the message? It doesn't make much sense to show it to veteran users.

Comment: @Yannis I hate the rep requirements to hide things that are static. It just means that when I go to look for the link so I can give it to another user, I can't find it. I understand hiding annoying dynamic things, like popups, but it doesn't bother me to see an extra word or line on static pages, and it only serves to aggravate me when I'm looking for the link later on.